# Can not show local images on webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am trying to add some local image icon after the url on web page in web view.

The piece of JS function code trying to execute is

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = 'file:///android_asset/high.png'; 
for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++)
{ 
    links.push(anchors[i].children[0].href); 
    var tag = anchors[i].children[0];
    tag.insertAdjacentHTML('AfterEnd', '&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=img alt=\"My Image\"/>');
}
```

Can not see the image appended, whereas I am getting error "Not Allowed to load local resources"
My question is Why I am not able to see images ? and also I am getting above error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758756/android-not-allowed-to-load-local-resourcefile-android-asset

Comment: There are similar post but they are about using loadUrl and so on. I want to load these images by using insertAdjacentHTML JS function.