# How to load JS & CSS from SDCARD with loadDataWithBaseURL() method

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, android-sdcard

I have a .html, .js, .css files on SDCARD, in my case html file contents are in encrypted form. I'm loading html file in following steps :

1. Read file content
2. Decrypt all content
3. Load all content into webview using below line :

   ```
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(relativePath, decFileContent, "text/html", 
                   "utf-8", null );
   ```

   here `relativePath = "file:///mnt/sdcard/MyFolder/"`

*What happens?*

It loads the decrypted content successfully, however not loading js & css files kept in relativePath folders named with JS/ & CSS/ respectively. It gives the following error dialog

> "Sorry! your application not support to local storageError: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"

Also, I searched for the above error & possible similar links are [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754288/using-webviews-loaddatawithbaseurl-not-loading-images-from-sdcard) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758756/android-not-allowed-to-load-local-resourcefile-android-asset)  in answers to these questions they have suggested to load js & css **from assets folder**. In my case I don't want load them from assets, **I want to load them from SDCARD**. Anybody have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm accessing content and was having a bit of trouble with the relativePath and got it working from something similar to your relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the entire path of the HTML file, not just the directory path in relativePath.

Or you can also use loadUrl

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Yes with full path it start working, thanks man you have solved my problem.