# Navigate to local page from external webpage in cordova android:not allowed to load local resource

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova

I am developing an mobile recharge application(including payment gateway) using cordova and angularjs.
Here is the work flow of payment process.

1.user fill the form that shows in app with necessary details(name,mobile-no,etc).

2.Launch the  payment gateway api in a webview(Now user can choose his payment method option and pay it).

3.After the transaction it redirect to another page and `POST` the transaction details.

4.In this page i want to display a button when click on that it launches the app.

I am Stuck with the step-4

code for launch the webview for payment

```
$scope.getPaymentWebView=function(){
       //launch the payment method webpage
       window.open('http://sample.com/atom','_self','location=no');          
     }
```

**return.php**

```
<?php
 //post the transaction data
  print_r($_POST)
?>
//go to app page from webview
<a href="file:///android_assets/www/index.html">Go to app</a>
```

I will get this error when click on my page

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///android_assets/www/index.html", source:
>   http://sample/atom/return.php

Comment: Heya shammon search for "Not allowed to load local resource: " android 

in google, there's a load of stack related answers

Comment: I've tried this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758756/android-not-allowed-to-load-local-resourcefile-android-asset) but i want load from an external page(web view)